# Is there a find and replace functions for SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress, replace, trim

I have some values in my SQL i want to trim and replace.
I want to look in a key field `_booking_persons` and only store all between `""` and remove the rest.

So at the moment i got this in all fields

```
s:14:"a:1:{i:0;i:4;}“
```

and i want to keep `a:1:{i:0;i:4;}` so everything between `" "`.

I tried to fix it with wordpress post_meta_update. So i tought maybe its easy to do that with SQL.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'wc_booking', 'posts_per_page' => '-1'  );                                              
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $array = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_booking_persons', true );
        $between = preg_replace('/(.*)"(.*)"(.*)/sm', '\2', $array);
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_booking_persons', $between );
    }

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

I expect `a:1:{i:0;i:4;}` but stay as it is `s:14:"a:1:{i:0;i:4;}“`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with substring_index function:

SELECT substring_index(substring_index('s:14:\"a:1:{i:0;i:4;}\"', '\"', 2), '\"', -1);

This will return:

a:1:{i:0;i:4;}

Note that you need to escape " character with \

You can see this in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/78099/0)

Comment: And how this fix my problem? It's nice that i return that :) But i need something to replace all the "fals" values in database. So that he use original value -> remove -> save new value. Such a update script.

Comment: @JohnDo you should only run a simple update statement, it should be something like `update wp_postmeta pm
set pm.meta_value = substring_index(substring_index(pm.meta_value, '\"', 2), '\"', -1)
where pm.meta_key = '_booking_persons';`